# How to search google sheet data only from one column using google apps script webapp?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I`m using this below method to search data from a google sheet using google apps scricpt. it`s working fine but can someone please tell me how to set search function to find data only from one column? for now it`s getting data related to keyword from whole data range. (Not expecting the change data range fix. I need to search keyword only in one column)

Reference site : https://www.bpwebs.com/create-web-forms-to-get-data-from-google-sheets/#index-file

Answer (score 3):

```
function searchonecol() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('SheetName');
  const sr = 2;//data start row
  const colnum = 1;//column number
  const haystack = sh.getRange(sr,colnum,sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1).getValues();
  haystack.forEach((r,i) => {
    if(r[0] == 'needle') {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('you just found the needle in the haystack');
    }
  });
}
```